# using jquery to operate sth on selected input parts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My goal is to change the font-format of the selected part of the input text using jQuery.
plz show me the way that works in firefox(if there isn't a way for it doesn't matter...). my problem is getting the selected part (ranges) and working with that ranges but i am not sure if its this way.plz show me the way.

```
 var userSelection;
 if (window.getSelection) {
     userSelection = window.getSelection();
 } else if (document.selection) { // Opera
     userSelection = document.selection.createRange();
 }
```

i am designing a full text editor using html.

Comment: Are you trying to change the font of a selected text inside a textarea? Please submit your HTML as well

Comment: @YoavKadosh yes,i am trying that.my html code is not a special large code.it is just a input tag inside a div and i thought there is no need to submit it.already i don't want everyone answer me for a single html version.

Comment: Something like this perhaps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312928/change-font-style-of-selected-text-in-javascript