# Change font for selected text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

How can I change the font when I highlight a specific text from the div. The code below changes the font of the whole text when I select a font from my dropbox.

```js
function changeFont(font) {
  document.getElementById("note_header").style.fontFamily = font.value;
}
```

```html
Highlight text and change font <br>
<select id="select_font" onchange="changeFont(this);">
            <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
            <option value="Sans Serif" selected>Sans Serif</option>
            <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
            <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
            <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
            <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
            <option value="Trebuchet MS">Trebuchet MS</option>
            <option value="Arial Black">Arial Black</option>
            <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
            <option value="Bookman">Bookman</option>
            <option value="Garamond">Garamond</option>
            <option value="Palatino">Palatino</option>
            <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
        </select>
<div contenteditable="true" id="note_header" style="width:200px; height:200px; border: 1px solid #ccc">
  Some Content
</div>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here. By highlighted, do you mean selecting characters with the cursor or do you mean the value selected from the dropdown?

Comment: Highlighting the text in the div, and changing the font from the dropdown

Comment: have a look on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312928/change-font-style-of-selected-text-in-javascript

Comment: @User786 use `window.getSelection()`

Comment: @User786 As the answer you accepted can add issues on repeated strings like "abc abc abc", because of the use of `replace()` ; I added a new answer that won't. Please review it. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Trying to enhance Ankit's answer,
Here is a solution that doesn't use the `replace()` function.

The issue with Ankit's solution is that the first occurence of a selected text was replaced in case of a text being repeated.
For example, when the text is "abc abc" and we selected the second one, that was the first one that got its font changed.

⋅
⋅
⋅

The snippet below creates a new html element with the selected text and the chosen font, then deletes the selection and inserts the new element at its place:
(See comments in the code)

```js
function changeFont(font) {
  var sel = window.getSelection(); // Gets selection
  if (sel.rangeCount) {
    // Creates a new element, and insert the selected text with the chosen font inside
    var e = document.createElement('span');
    e.style = 'font-family:' + font.value + ';'; 
    e.innerHTML = sel.toString();

    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/getRangeAt
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    range.deleteContents(); // Deletes selected text…
    range.insertNode(e); // … and inserts the new element at its place
  }
}
```

```css
.editable {
  width: 360px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
Highlight text and change font <br>
<select id="select_font" onchange="changeFont(this);">
  <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
  <option value="Sans Serif" selected>Sans Serif</option>
  <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
  <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
  <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
  <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
  <option value="Trebuchet MS">Trebuchet MS</option>
  <option value="Arial Black">Arial Black</option>
  <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
  <option value="Bookman">Bookman</option>
  <option value="Garamond">Garamond</option>
  <option value="Palatino">Palatino</option>
  <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
</select>
<div contenteditable="true" class="editable">
  Some Content
</div>
```

Note that jQuery isn't unnecessarily added.
(OP didn't used it in their question)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Could you please also explain how your solution works?

Comment: @vibhor1997a sure, I'm going to do so and add comments in my code.

Comment: This is not working properly, Let's say you set a text as bold and select all content and set a new font family, it will lose its formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `window.getSelection()` to get the selected text from the `div` and since you are just willing to change the highlighted text so you can surround the highlighted text with `<span>` element and then apply the `font-family` css to that `<span>`. This `<span>` element will hold the highlighted text so the `font-family` will be changed to this highlighted text only.

```js
function changeFont(font) {
    var selectedText = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
      selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
      var newContent = $('#note_header').html().replace(selectedText, '<span style="font-family:'+font.value+';">'+selectedText+'</span>');
      $('#note_header').html(newContent);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Highlight text and change font <br>
<select id="select_font" onchange="changeFont(this);">
            <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
            <option value="Sans Serif" selected>Sans Serif</option>
            <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
            <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
            <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
            <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
            <option value="Trebuchet MS">Trebuchet MS</option>
            <option value="Arial Black">Arial Black</option>
            <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
            <option value="Bookman">Bookman</option>
            <option value="Garamond">Garamond</option>
            <option value="Palatino">Palatino</option>
            <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
        </select>
<div contenteditable="true" id="note_header" style="width:200px; height:200px; border: 1px solid #ccc">
  Some Content
</div>
```

Comment: But wouldn't that change only the first occurence of the selected text in the div. Lets say if `abc` appears twice and the abc occuring `2nd` is selected. Still the `1st` abc would get changed.

Comment: That won't always work correctly because `.replace` function replaces the first instance of matching text. It may not necessarily be the highlighted text.

Comment: Select the text from your mouse (highlight) and then select the option from dropdown. It will change the font family of the highlighted text. Haven't you guys used google doc or word? If you select the word or text and then `bold` it, does it bold all the occurrence of that word? @vibhor1997a

Comment: @Nisarg we need to replace the highlighted text and highlighted text is always one and it cannot be multiple inside that `div` first go through the logic

Comment: @Sinto check my comments to get the changed font

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Write `Some Content Some Content` in the div, and then select the second `Some Content`. Now if you change the font, the first part of text will change.

Comment: @Nisarg that is exactly what's require. Change the highlighted text only and not all the occurrence of what is highlighted

Comment: @Nisarg check what OP has written `How can I change the font when I highlight a specific text from the div.` only specific text and not all the occurrence of what's highlighted

Comment: @Ankit That won't actually happen when there are multiple strings matching the highlighted text. I will see if I can post an answer to explain your mistake.

Comment: @Nisarg in MS Word when you bold a word after highlighting it, then would you get all the occurrence of that word to bold?

Comment: @Ankit Try this: Write `Some Content Some Content` in the div, and then select the second Some Content `Some Content [Some Content]`. Now if you change the font, the first part of text will change `[Some Content] Some Content`.

Comment: Ankit, we're not downvoting for fun, we're downvoting because of the issue you don't seem to understand. @vibhor1997a told you the first and you mocked them by using a comparison with google doc or word without understanding what you did wrong.

Comment: Then @Nisarg tried to explain it to you too. Please open your eyes and understand, now. No hate here, just commenting to make things clear. And enchance the solution.

Answer (score -3):

You can try this:

```js
function changeFont(font) {
  document.getElementById("note_header").style.fontFamily= font.value;
  document.getElementById("select_font").setAttribute(
   "style", "border: 1px solid red; outline: none");
   }
```

```html
<select id="select_font" onchange="changeFont(this);">
            <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
            <option value="Sans Serif" selected>Sans Serif</option>
            <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
            <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
            <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
            <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
            <option value="Trebuchet MS">Trebuchet MS</option>
            <option value="Arial Black">Arial Black</option>
            <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
            <option value="Bookman">Bookman</option>
            <option value="Garamond">Garamond</option>
            <option value="Palatino">Palatino</option>
            <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
        </select>
<div contenteditable="true" id="note_header" style="width:200px; height:200px; border: 1px solid #ccc">
  Some Content
</div>
```

Comment: The reason people have downvoted because the required answer was to select only a portion of the content and not everything. Perhaps you misunderstood the problem but that's alright.