# select a text from textarea and press the button to make them bold

Tags: javascript, html, css

when someone has selected text and press the bold button the selected text will be bold and not all the textarea characters.

```js
document.getElementById("bold").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("textarea").style.fontWeight = "800";
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<button id="bold">Make bold</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't style text inside of a textarea more then in your example.

But you can try this attempt with editable div: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50287002/4230037